# Image Origin in JScrollPane above JScrollPane origin

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, bufferedimage, jviewport

I'm a programming novice, so please forgive me if this is an obvious question but I am working on an application that, amongst other things, builds a Gantt Chart.

The problem I have is that one of the panels (namesPanel) shows the relevant image,but with around 10 pixels missing from the top. I can get the image to seem correct by adding 10 pixels to the startpoint of the y variable whilst drawing, but this just doesn't feel right and if there's a bug I want to squash it now.

The chart is actually made up of three different JScrollPanes nested in a JPanel, arranged with a GridBagLayout:

```
    datesPanel = new JScrollPane();
    datesPane = new GanttPanel();
    panelList.put(datesPanel, datesPane);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.1;
    c.weighty = 0.1;
    add(datesPanel, c);

    namesPanel = new JScrollPane();
    namesPane = new GanttPanel();
    panelList.put(namesPanel, namesPane);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.18;
    c.weighty = 1;
    add(namesPanel, c);

    ganttPanel = new JScrollPane();
    ganttPane = new GanttPanel();
    panelList.put(ganttPanel, ganttPane);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    add(ganttPanel, c);

    for (JScrollPane j : panelList.keySet()) {
        GanttPanel g = panelList.get(j);
        j.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        j.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        j.addMouseListener(listener);
        LineBorder b = (LineBorder) BorderFactory.createLineBorder(DARK);
        j.setBorder(b);
        j.setViewportView(g);
    }

    namesImage = (BufferedImage) namesPane.createImage(canvasWidth, canvasDepth);
    namesPane.setImage(namesImage);
    namesGraphics = (Graphics2D) namesImage.getGraphics();

    datesImage = (BufferedImage) datesPane.createImage(canvasWidth, canvasDepth);
    datesPane.setImage(datesImage);
    datesGraphics = (Graphics2D) datesImage.getGraphics();        

    ganttImage = (BufferedImage) ganttPane.createImage(canvasWidth, canvasDepth);
    ganttPane.setImage(ganttImage);
    graphics = (Graphics2D) ganttImage.getGraphics();
```

The reason for this is to allow the user to scroll around the ganttChart using the mouse, so later on the scrollbars of namesPanel and datesPanel are set to the same instance of JScrollBar as the ganttChart.

The program then goes on to resize all the images in order to save on memory - the reason that they are all set to the same size at first is that certain graphics calculations are required to set the bounds of the eventual images and that means creating an image to get the graphics object from. Also, I don't know how to make an image larger:

```
 /**
 * Sets the boundaries of all the panels and moves them into position
 */
private void setBounds()
{
    int xStart = canvasWidth - xOffset;
    int yStart = canvasDepth - yOffset;
    Container dad = getParent();
    Rectangle dadRect = dad.getBounds();
    Dimension ganttSize = new Dimension(dadRect.width - xOffset, dadRect.height - yOffset);

    ganttImage = ganttImage.getSubimage(0, 0, xStart, yStart);
    ganttPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xStart, yStart));
    ganttPanel.setPreferredSize(ganttSize);

    datesImage = datesImage.getSubimage(0, 0, xStart, (yOffset + yUnit));
    datesPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xStart, yOffset));
    datesPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xStart, yOffset));

    namesImage = namesImage.getSubimage(0, 0, xOffset, yOffset);
    namesPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xOffset, yStart));
    namesPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xOffset, yStart));
    namesPanel.setBackground(DARK);

}
```

Finally, the program actually draws the image - I know this area needs some refactoring into submethods, but here it is:

```
    /**
 * Draw the bars of the Gantt Chart
 */
private void drawBars()
{
    Calendar from = model.getFrom();
    int i = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < canvasDepth && i < elements.size(); y += yUnit) {
        GanttElement ge = elements.get(i);
        //TODO refactor this section into multiple methods
        int startPoint = 0;
        int endPoint = 0;
        try {
            startPoint = (model.calculateRange(from, ge.getFrom()) * xUnit);
            if (startPoint % 10 != 0) {
                startPoint -= startPoint % 10;
            }
            endPoint = (model.calculateRange(from, ge.getTo()) * xUnit);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException | BadDateException e) {
            /*TODO add a badDateResponse method to the GanttElement interface
             *so that the program can handle a bad date request appropriately 
             */
            System.out.println(e + " " + ge.getName());
        }
        for (int x = 0; x <= endPoint; x += xUnit) {
            if (x == 0) {
                namesGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                namesGraphics.drawString(ge.getName(), (2 * getSeparatorX()), y);
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                graphics.setColor(lightBlock);
            }
            else {
                graphics.setColor(darkBlock);
            }
            if (x >= startPoint) {
                GanttBlock block = new GanttBlock(x + (separatorX / 2), y, blockWidth, rowHeight, i);
                blocks.add(block);
                graphics.fill(block);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I'm stumped - I can't locate the line that's causing the problem and I can't see any difference from the way I handle the namesPanel to the way I handle the others. Altering the fields that affect image placement and dimensions doesn't help either. Neither does manipulating the JViewport. :-(

Once again, apologies if this is too long but I don't know what area of the code to focus on.